# Split string after first word using ArcMap 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, field-calculator

I want to split a string field after the first word using the space as a delimiter so that:

```
"WA ROSSOUW ORANJE BELEGGINGS" becomes "ROSSOUW ORANJE BELEGGINGS".
```

I am using ArcMap 10.

Comment: This worked for me. THANKS! Incidentally, if I just wanted to extract ONLY the first word, how would you suggest I modify the VBA code?

Answer (score 7):

Or the two-liner using Python:

(in Show Codeblock)

```
    import string
```

in Class = :

```
string.join(!YourFieldName!.lstrip().split(' ')[1:],' ')
```

The `lstrip()` makes sure there are no leading spaces which will cause problems

Comment: Python string module functions are deprecated (http://docs.python.org/library/string.html).  String object methods are preferred, e.g. ' '.join(!YourFieldName!.lstrip().split(' ')[1:])

Comment: shorter too, so can't argue with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the following VBA code in field calculator :

```
Split( [Your_Field_Name] , " ", 2)(1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting a "failure during processing" message when I use it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use python if you want.

```
text = "WA ROSSOUW ORANJE BELEGGINGS"
sptext = text.split(" ") 
result = ' '.join(sptext[1:len(sptext)])
print result

>>>"ROSSOUW ORANJE BELEGGINGS"
```